# C passing nested structure as reference

Tags: c, struct, reference

I am trying to define different features in different structures. But program neither working nor giving error. I expect printer function to print the values that I defined. But giving nothing at consol screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}points;

typedef struct
{

    points *dimensions;
    int ID;
    char *name;

}features;

void printer(features *test)
{
    printf("dimensions = [ %d %d %d ]\r\n",test->dimensions->x,test->dimensions->y,test->dimensions->z);
    printf(" ID = %d, name= %s\r\n",test->ID,test->name);

}

int main()
{
    features *ball;
    ball->dimensions->x = 10;
    ball->dimensions->y = -5;
    ball->dimensions->z = 15;
    ball->ID           = 121121;
    ball->name         = "redball";

    printer(ball);
return 0;
}
```

I am sure there is only a little mistake I cant see now.

Comment: Also define "not working".

Comment: `warning: 'ball' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]` - pointers have to point at *something*.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, I see. but ball is defined as same type.

Comment: `ball` is a pointer, but where does it point to?

Comment: `ball` is clearly *defined*, but not *initialized*. It's not set to point at anything, so it points who knows where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ball` and `dimensions` are just *pointers*. But they both *point* to nowhere.

You need to allocate memory for where they should pointing to for both, f.e. by using `malloc()`, and assign the address of the memory to the pointers:

```
features *ball = malloc (sizeof(features));   // Memory for structure features allocated and assigned to pointer.
ball->dimensions = malloc (sizeof(points));   // Memory for structure points allocated and assigned to pointer.
```

---

In your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
} points;

typedef struct
{
   points *dimensions;
   int ID;
   char *name;
} features;

void printer (features *test)
{
   printf("dimensions = [ %d %d %d ]\r\n", test->dimensions->x, test->dimensions->y, test->dimensions->z);
   printf("ID = %d, name = %s\r\n", test->ID, test->name);
}

int main (void)
{
   features *ball = malloc (sizeof(features));   // Memory for structure features allocated.
   ball->dimensions = malloc (sizeof(points));   // Memory for structure points allocated.

   ball->dimensions->x = 10;
   ball->dimensions->y = -5;
   ball->dimensions->z = 15;
   ball->ID = 121121;
   ball->name = "redball";

   printer(ball);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
dimensions = [ 10 -5 15 ]
ID = 121121, name = redball
```

Comment: Thank you! now I see why it does not give any outputs.